# Using node.js and wcf.js in aws lambda to contact a wcf .net service not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I got this completely working on my personal computer using powershell and node.js and when I submit via ask cli to aws lambda the proxy.send does nothing, no error, no sign of even attempting to function properly.  I'm not sure how to find out what is wrong or where to go from here.

The idea is to send in two strings to the .net WCF service and the service will use them and spit back the text Alexa will eventually speak.  I have put console.log all over this and it seems that everything plays out, but the console.log placed inside the proxy.send function never fires.  I get no errors in the log.

Please note: Everything always works accept for the BasicHttpBinding and the proxy.send lines.  I have no confirmation they are doing anything correctly as I get no error.

```
    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
    , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
    , binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
    , proxy = new Proxy(binding, "http://service.menofnoblegirth.com/service1.svc")
    , message = "<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
             "<Header />" +
               "<Body>" +
                 "<GetData xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>" +
                   "<value>test</value>" +
                   "<value2>test2</value2>" +
                 "</GetData>" +
                "</Body>" +
           "</Envelope>"
    proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", function (response, ctx) {
    parseString(response, function(error, result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        var stringfun = JSON.stringify(result);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(stringfun);
        console.log(objectValue["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0]);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').Parser();
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
, Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
, binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
, proxy = new Proxy(binding, "http://service.menofnoblegirth.com/service1.svc")
, message = "<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
         "<Header />" +
           "<Body>" +
             "<GetData xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>" +
               "<value>test</value>" +
               "<value2>test2</value2>" +
             "</GetData>" +
            "</Body>" +
       "</Envelope>"
proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", function (response, ctx) {
parseString.parseString(response, function(error, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    var stringfun = JSON.stringify(result);
    var objectValue = JSON.parse(stringfun);
    console.log(objectValue["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0]);
    });

});
```

Comment: I think that this is just the code copy and pasted as an answer?

Comment: Ahh not sure the original code actually worked but being it's hitting a external service it needed more than the default 3 seconds.  Thanks for replying and I appreciate your help.  I was pulling my hair out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This code is functional but the 3 second time out by default on an Alexa skill needs to be increased to 4-14 seconds.

Two things happen.  The "hosted" website that housed the WCF service goes to sleep and it takes up to 14 seconds for the service to wake and response on the first call. (1400 milliseconds)

The second thing that happens is a regular call once the service is awake can take 309 milliseconds which is 9 more milliseconds than the default timeout.